# how to add my own shape file trajLevel() in openair package R

Tags: r, maps, mapping, openair

I am using this following code for plotting the trajectories...........

```html
library(openair)

load("GDASNDL1000m.Rdata")

trajLevel(traj,method="hexbin",col="jet",xbin=40,parameters=NULL,
orientation=c(90,0,0),projection="mercator")
```

[result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ONzun.png) https://github.com/adeckmyn/maps/files/2667752/GDASNDL1000m.zip

Here, I would like to change the base `world map` with my own `shape file`.

my shape file is follows....

```html
z1=maptools::readShapePoly("/home/sateeshm/shapefiles/ncmrwf/india_map")
library(maps)
map(z1)
```

https://github.com/adeckmyn/maps/files/2667336/World-India.zip

#

Now, the actual question is **how to link z1 to trajLevel?**

Answer (score 0):

To avoid the hard-coded call to "world" in openair, you wil have to create a new world database in the same file based format as that of the "maps" package.

Probably the simplest way to do this, is to use the [mapMaker](https://github.com/adeckmyn/mapMaker) package. This package is not on CRAN but can be found on github. It is the package I used to create the standard world map. The documentation is minimal, but if you don't care about polygon names etc, you can create a "quick and dirty" world map as follows:

```
# get your new map as a simple list of polygons (or lines)
z1=maps::map(maptools::readShapePoly("india_map"), plot=FALSE)
# create internal representation
z2=mapMaker::map.make(z1)
# write binary files:
mapMaker::map.export.bin(z2, "/my/path/to/world")

# To make map() call this new database:
library(maps)
worldMapEnv="MYMAP"
Sys.setenv("MYMAP"="/my/path/to/") # don't add the "world" !
```

now `map("world")` will draw your version of the world map.

Comment: Dear @Alex, Currently, my india_map is 180W to 180E. Is it possible to customize my india_map as 0 to 360 or 90W to 0,180E,270E with mapMaker ?. If so, give some more information.

Comment: Yes, this is in fact quite easy. When calling the map() function, just add the option wrap=c(0,360) (or any two latitudes). Note that if fill=T, this will split the polygons that cross the meridian. However, it will not magically blend polygons that were split at the 180 meridian. So there may remain a few superfluous lines in the map. Removing those may require manual editing.

Comment: > map("world",wrap=c(-60,300))
Warning message:
In if (wrap) coord <- map.wrap(coord) :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used    \n Here, I used india_map.shp

Comment: you probably have an older version of the maps package, without the new wrapping syntax. The current version on CRAN, v3.3, should not give this error.